# why/ how does VRFCoordinatorV2 automatically fulfill randomness when LINK is deposited?

Tags: blockchain, chainlink, vrf, chainlink-vrf

0

In my smart contract I've created an instances of both the LINK and VRFCoordinatorV2.sol contracts. I am also listening for the 'RandomWordsFulfilled' event which is emitted when 'fulfillRandomWords' is called by the Oracle who is obviously listening to the coordinator contract.

I've noticed that 'RandomWordsFulfilled' is triggered any time I transfer [a sufficient amoutn of] LINK to the coordinator contract, even though I've not explicitly called 'requestRandomWords'.

Why? I'd like to fund my contract with LINK so I can make requests in a CONTROLLED and PREDICTABLE fashion, i.e. when I actaully make a request.

I know of no publicly available contract that would show us what events are being listened to or how the oracle responds. As the name implies, the 'coordinator' contract is just to coordinate between the requester (me) and the oracle that responds. The chainlink docs do not seem to clarify this behavior.both both